# Installing OpenCV 2.1 problems

Tags: opencv

I want to install openCV in my ubuntu 12.04 but I get this following error.

```
[ 45%] Building CXX object src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore_pch_dephelp.dir/cxcore_pch_dephelp.o
In file included from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1826:0,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/_cxcore.h:51,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/release/src/cxcore/cxcore_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:177:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
In file included from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2307:0,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1826,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/_cxcore.h:51,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/release/src/cxcore/cxcore_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:2043:15: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:2591:31: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
In file included from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2308:0,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1826,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/_cxcore.h:51,
from /home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/release/src/cxcore/cxcore_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function ‘void cv::Mat::locateROI(cv::Size&, cv::Point&) const’:
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:387:5: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:387:5: note: suggested alternatives:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:156:28: note: ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:156:28: note: ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:387:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘delta1’
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:389:9: error: ‘delta1’ was not declared in this scope
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:398:31: error: ‘delta2’ was not declared in this scope
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function ‘cv::Point cv::MatConstIterator_::pos() const’:
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3459:9: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3459:9: note: suggested alternatives:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:156:28: note: ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:156:28: note: ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3459:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ofs’
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3460:23: error: ‘ofs’ was not declared in this scope
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3460:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘y’
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3465:9: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3465:9: note: suggested alternatives:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:156:28: note: ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:156:28: note: ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3465:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ofs’
/home/michael/Downloads/open cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3466:23: error: ‘ofs’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore_pch_dephelp.dir/cxcore_pch_dephelp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried adding `#include <stddef.h>` in cxcore.hpp, but then I get this error

```
[ 45%] Built target opencv_lapack
[ 45%] Building CXX object src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore_pch_dephelp.dir/cxcore_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libcxcore_pch_dephelp.a
[ 45%] Built target cxcore_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_cxcore
[ 45%] Generating _cxcore.h
[ 45%] Generating _cxcore.h.gch/cxcore_RELEASE.gch
c++: error: cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/.: No such file or directory
c++: error: cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/release: No such file or directory
c++: error: cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include: No such file or directory
c++: error: cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv: No such file or directory
c++: error: cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/../../3rdparty/include: No such file or directory
c++: error: cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/../../include/opencv: No such file or directory
c++: error: cv/OpenCV-2.1.0/release/src/cxcore: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [src/cxcore/_cxcore.h.gch/cxcore_RELEASE.gch] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_cxcore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to fix this problem? Is it impossible to install this version of openCV in ubuntu 12.04. Any help will be appreciated.
:)

Comment: why are you even trying with 2.1 , when the current one is 2.4.8 ?

Comment: I use this version because my embedded PC uses 2.1. The purpose of this is because I'm working with robot. Therefore I need to use 2.1 version in my laptop.